# change specific component of list in R

Tags: r, list

I try to change a specific component `L[[2]]` in a list `L` in R. Unfortunately, the other component `L[[1]]` in the list changes as well. Below is a minimal working example:

```
 # initialize list L:
 L <- matrix(list( matrix(0,1,2) ), 2, 1)
 # show that L[[1]] = c(0,0):
 print(L[[1]][1,])
 #>[1] 0 0
 # only change L[[2]] into c(1,1):
 L[[2]][1,]   <- 1 
 # however L[[1]] has changed too to c(1,1):
 print(L[[1]][1,])
 #>[1] 1 1
```

(Maybe this is a basic question as I am not an expert in R.)

In response to Akrun's comment:
The change in `L[[1]]` occurs when I run the complete code *in one go* in the editor of R-studio. Somehow the change in `L[1]` does not occur when I run the four commands at the command line *one at a time*. Seems very strange to me.

Comment: Restarting RStudio does not help.

Comment: It mut be due to the structure of the nested matrix. Try `l1 <- lapply(L, I); l1[[2]][] <- 1;L[] <- l1`

Comment: @akrun what does `I` do ?

Comment: When you create your list differently. e.g. `L <- rep(list( matrix(0,1,2)),2)`, this doesn't happen

Comment: I think you could do `L[2][[1]][] <- 1`.  Now checkihg `print(L[[1]][1,])#
[1] 0 0`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think slightly different: Replacing the first command by `L     <- list( matrix(0,1,2), matrix(0,1,2) )` resolved the issue.
Still strange that with the original nested matrix command the one-go run produced a different result than the stepwise run.

Comment: @Sander Now, it is a `list` of `matrices`.  You need `L[[1]][] <- 1`

Comment: I get the same result whether it is run all at once or one line at a time.

Comment: This was a bug in R, which has now been fixed.  See https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=17514.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to tackle this.  The structure is a bit convoluted to make the changes as we do in regular `list`.  It is a `list` with dimension attributes given by `matrix` and is complicated by having a `list` of `matric`es

**1)**  The `list` object is created within a `matrix` and it is a `list` of `matrices`.  So, we could assign the values based on subsetting the elements of the `matrix` first and then extract the `list` component to assign it to 1

```
L[2][[1]][] <- 1
print(L[[1]][1,])
#[1] 0 0
```

**2)** Another option is to create a temporary `list` object and assign the values on the `list`, update the `matrix/list` later with the changed `list`

```
l1 <- lapply(L, I) # I stands for identity.
l1[[2]][] <- 1
L[] <- l1
print(L[[1]][1,])
#[1] 0 0
```

Comment: However, the OP pointed out correctly that the assignment works when running the code line by line. Why is running it line by line different than running the code as a chunk?

Comment: @Tjebo  The struxture is complicated by `list` wrapped in a `matrix`.  So, if I extract the `list` as `L[[1]]`, it is kind of disturbing the underlying structure.  But, if we do `L[1, 1][[1]][] <- 1` the assignment happens at the correct element

Comment: thanks! Good that I never tried to create a list like that :) Anyways, peculiar situation and I think very interesting.